# overflow:hidden; strange behavior at Internet Explorer on mouse over

Tags: internet-explorer, css

On mouse over, the size of the menu increases on **Internet Explorer 9.0.8**.
I found out that the reason was that the element `divider` was using the property `overflow:hidden`.

Why does it influence the element when the mouse is over?

Here's the fiddle with the code. I have pointed in the first CSS style where is the problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/EF9Eg/4/

This is the problematic style:

```
.floatingMenu li.divider{
    height: 1px;
    margin: 9px 1px;
    overflow:hidden;  /*PROBLEM INTERNET EXPLORER*/
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

If we get rid of the `overflow:hidden;` everything works well.

Comment: your fiddle seems to work fine for me in ie9, but an idea would be to put a different class on your non dividers and just do the hover events for those lis instead of all of them

Comment: @Pete It is not working well when you move the mouse over the menu. It becomes bigger.

Comment: have you tried to give `zoom : 1;` to the li's?

Comment: Is there any reason you're opposed to just giving the ul a width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening it would seem based off an alternate interpretation on IE's part of the 100% width and what div is defining that size.

100% width in a div or ul that has no set or max width could be interpretted as being the width of the largest div it is nested in, which is what appears to be happening. If you remove the 100% width or apply a set or max-width to the ul, it will confine it to that hierarchical width.

This may in part also be a factor of the absolute positioning applied to the ul, since it may ignore relatively positioned divs' width higher than itself.

I believe [this](http://devign.me/css-stretch-a-box-to-its-parent-bounds/) explains what is happening further.

Answer (score 0):

Problem disappears when you remove width:100% from .floatingMenu li

Comment: I know it, but... why it makes the parent bigger on mouse over? Does anybody see the logic under it?